# Hibernate - How to eagerly load lazy fields?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a entity with multiple lazy fields -

```
@Entity 
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountIdfk", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Address> addresses;
    .....
}
```

In some scenarios, I need to load addresses eagerly. 
Normally we call below query to fetch the entity -

```
dataStore.get().type(clazz).pk(id).execute();
```

Is there a way, we can pass any additional parameter or something in the above query to load the addresses at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamic fetching via queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching) (`JOIN FETCH`):

```
Account account = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select a " +
    "from Account a " +
    "left join fetch a.addresses " +
    "where a.id = :id",
    Account.class)
.setParameter( "id", id)
.getSingleResult();
```

Also you can use dynamic fetching via *JPA entity graph*. More details you can find by the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to solutions in @SternK's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62022037/7598851), you could use [Spring Data JPA @Query](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query), [@NamedQuery](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-named-queries/) or [@NamedNativeQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedNativeQuery.html).

Here's a `@NamedQuery` example:

```
@Entity 
@NamedQuery(name = "Account.findAccountWithAddress",
        query = "SELECT a FROM Account a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.addresses AS addr WHERE a.id = :id")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountIdfk", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Address> addresses;
    .....
}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

    Optional<Account> findAccountWithAddress(Long id);
}
```